# Get the string between two other strings

Tags: php, string

I have this `total USD100.75 from` string.I am getting the next word like this

```
$s = 'total USD100.75 from';
$r = preg_match_all('/(?<=(total))(\s\w*)/',$s,$matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

However i would like to get the string between two specific strings i.e `total` and `from`. How may i get the middle string?.

Comment: Please check my answer, It will resolve your issue. Let me know still you face any issues.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.Elon's answer suited my situation better,not that yours is not a great answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use regexp for that, eg.

```
'/total (.*?) from/'
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `substr` and `strlen`:

```
echo substr($string, strlen("total "), -strlen(" from"));
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of the specifics of your language, but in Java:

```
(?USD[0-9]+\.[0-9]{2})
```

would work.

1. "USD", followed by
2. One or more numerals, followed by
3. Literal ".",
4. followed by two numerals.

If you have commas, you could try:

```
(?USD[0-9]{1,3}(,?[0-9]{3})*\.[0-9]{2})
```

1. "USD" followed by 1-3 numerals, followed by,
2. any number of groups of: an optional comma followed by 3 numerals, followed by
3. a decimal, followed by
4. two digits

Comment: Great answer Nields.I will use your answer when i port my app to java in a months time.

Answer (score 0):

You can explode your string by space.

```
$s = 'total USD100.75 from';    
$s1 = explode(" ", $s);
echo $s1[1];
```

**Output**

```
USD100.75
```

**[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/fRhGU1)**

Answer (score 0):

The regular expressions are easy way to do it. You just need to understand the basics. 
You will achieve what you want with the following pattern:

```
total\s(.*)\sfrom
```

Answer (score 0):

@user3272483, Please check below answer for your solution.

```
$matches = array();
preg_match("/total (.*?) from/", 'total USD100.75 from', $matches);
print_r($matches);
```